# Link no terminal

Tags: javascript, express.js, terminal

Existe alguma forma de fazer com que quando o `localhost:3000`, que está no terminal, seja pressionado `ctrl` *+* `click` o browser seja aberto na página em questão ( *localhost:3000* ) ... isso em um código Javascript :

```
console.log('\nServidor iniciado em \033[36mlocalhost:3000\033[37m\n')
```

**Obs** : Pesquisei porém só encontro referências de como criar um link em Html `<a>`: (`</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que atalho não seja possível, mas você pode executar comando para abrir. Abaixo exemplos, ao executar:

```
npm start
```

Automaticamente irá abrir o navegador, após iniciar o **App**. Adicione um dos códigos abaixo no **package.json** de seu projecto.

No *Linux*:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js && xdg-open http://localhost:3000"
}
```

No *Mac*:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js && open http://localhost:3000"
}
```

No *Windows*:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js && start http://localhost:3000"
}
```